# How to display first post of each tag

Tags: wordpress

I have multiple posts, some of them have same tag, i need to display only first posts of each tag. I was unable to find the solution on google or here.

Wordpress codex show this as example which displays each tag. Is this possible to combine with the query posts

```js
<?php $tags = get_tags();
$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
 $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );
   
 $html .= "<a href='{$tag_link}' title='{$tag->name} Tag' class='{$tag->slug}'>";
 $html .= "{$tag->name}</a>";
}
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only you have to do it, just call a post query with specific post tag inside your each tag loop as follows -

```
$tags = get_tags();
$html = '<div class="post_tags">';
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) :
    $tag_link = get_tag_link( $tag->term_id );

    $html .= '<a href="'.$tag_link.'" title="'.$tag->name.' Tag" class="'.$tag->slug.'">'.$tag->name.'</a>';
    // fetch tag specific post
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'   => 1,
        'order'         => 'ASC',
        'tax_query'     => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_tag',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $tag->slug
            )
        )
    );
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );
    foreach ( $postslist as $post ) :
        $html .= '<h2><a href="'.get_the_permalink( $post->ID ).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></h2>';
        $html .= $post->post_content;
    endforeach; 
endforeach;
$html .= '</div>';
echo $html;
```

Comment: @AjdinAlic, sorry there was a missing dot over the tag slug on anchor link. Anyways I updated my code. You can check it now.